# How to call internal function in react component from different component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, linear-gradients, react-spring

I've created a component that uses a css linear-gradient to render a random linear gradient.

When the user presses a button located somewhere else in my component tree (header), I want the gradient to:

1. Randomly generate a new gradient
2. Interpolate the new and old values using react spring

#### What is the best way to do this? I need to call the `genColor()` function/ force the component to re-render  after it has rendered. Can I call an internal function via a prop?

[image]

```js
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { animated, useSpring } from "react-spring"

const Gradient = styled(animated.div)`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
`

const Sky = () => {

  const generateColor = () => {
    let deviation = 33

    let r = Math.random() * deviation + (200 - deviation)
    let g = Math.random() * deviation + (119 - deviation)
    let b = Math.random() * deviation + (88 - deviation)

    r = Math.floor(r)
    g = Math.floor(g)
    b = Math.floor(b)

    let genColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
    return genColor
  }

  const interpolate = useSpring({
    background: `linear-gradient(180deg, black, #0d0e1c, #60697F, ${generateColor()})`,
    from: {
      background: `linear-gradient(180deg, black, #0d0e1c, #60697F, ${generateColor()})`,
    },
  })

  return <Gradient style={interpolate} />
}

export default Sky
```

Comment: What is `deviation`?

Comment: It's just a variable that helps me confine the output to a specific color range

Comment: If you pass it into `Sky` as a prop it would re-render when the value changes.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking too. Makes things less modular though. I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Or you could just pass the result of `generateColor()` as a prop into `Sky`.